# Are .NET enum types actually mutable value types?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, enums, immutability

Looking, with reflection, at the fields of an enum type, I noticed to my surprise that the "backing" instance field that holds the actual value of a particular instance of the enum is not `private`, as I would have thought, but `public`. And it was not `readonly` either. (`IsPublic` true, `IsInitOnly` false.)

Many people consider "mutable" value types in the .NET type system "evil", so **why are the enum types** (as created from C# code for example) **just that?**

Now, as it turns out, the C# compiler has some kind of magic that denies the existence of the public instance field (but see below), but in e.g. PowerShell you can do this:

```
prompt> $d = [DayOfWeek]::Thursday
prompt> $d
Thursday
prompt> $d.value__ = 6
prompt> $d
Saturday
```

The field `value__` can be written to.

Now, to do this in C#, I had to use `dynamic` because it seems that with the normal compile-time member binding, C# pretends that the `public` instance field does not exist. Of course to use `dynamic`, we will have to use *boxing* of the enum value.

Here's a C# code example:

```
// create a single box for all of this example
Enum box = DayOfWeek.Thursday;

// add box to a hash set
var hs = new HashSet<Enum> { box, };

// make a dynamic reference to the same box
dynamic boxDyn = box;

// see and modify the public instance field
Console.WriteLine(boxDyn.value__);  // 4
boxDyn.value__ = 6;
Console.WriteLine(boxDyn.value__);  // 6 now

// write out box
Console.WriteLine(box);  // Saturday, not Thursday

// see if box can be found inside our hash set
Console.WriteLine(hs.Contains(box));  // False

// we know box is in there
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(hs.Single(), box));  // True
```

I think the comments speak for themselves. We can mutate an instance of the enum type `DayOfWeek` (could be any enum type from a BCL assembly or from a "home-made" assembly) through a `public` field. Since the instance was in a hashtable and the mutation lead to a change of hash code, the instance is in the wrong "bucket" after the mutation, and the `HashSet<>` cannot function.

**Why did the designers of .NET choose to make the instance field of enum types `public`?**

Comment: I'm wondering about you ideas of what would be an ideal implementation. Are you willing to share?

Comment: Actually there is a much simpler way to prove that enum types are mutable, without boxing or dynamic: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/6100447

Comment: @KenKin Well, most of all, my idea is that the instance field that holds the actual value of the current instance should be `private`. Whether its name included "funny" characters (characters impossible in identifyer names in C#) or not, would be less important then, in my opinion.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque With that, you can even "mutate" truely immutable types like `DateTime` (change private field `ulong dateData`) or even so-called primitive types like `int` (change private field `int m_value`). The only change you would need to do, is to specify `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic` in the `GetField` call. But I don't think it's a problem that you can mutate anything with reflection. That's the nature of reflection. (Interesting with the `__makeref` C# keyword though, to avoid copy-by-value boxing.) The examples I gave above work only because `value__` is public.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, good point. I forgot that reflection lets you change readonly fields...

Comment: All non-trivial value types are mutable.  Struct assignment overwrites all the fields of an instance with values taken from another instance, and is done without involving any code within the structure type itself.

Comment: @supercat You: _"All non-trivial value types are mutable."_ That's good for you. Then your job of convincing the world that mutable value types are ___not___ evil is much easier :-) However, for the scope of this question, I define a "mutable value type" as a value type that can be mutated by accessing a `public` member of the value type itself. Public constuctors excluded. I don't consider `DateTime` mutable, for example, even if assigning to a `DateTime` variable means overwriting its private (64-bit integer type) instance field on the "micro-level".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It makes sense for a type like `DateTime` to hide its public field, since there's no exposed method to ascertain what the field value is in a given instance, nor to create an instance with a particular non-zero value in its field.  Having the field private allows implementations to change its meaning; that it's mutable will only matter in corner cases.  Something like an `enum`, however, has defined semantics which require it to encapsulate its underlying integral type.  There's nothing about its implementation which can really change, so there's no point hiding it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let me try to make sense of this rather confusing question for readers who are unfamiliar with how enums are generated behind the scenes. The C# code:

```
enum E { A, B }
```

becomes the IL

```
.class private auto ansi sealed E extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
  .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
  .field public static literal valuetype E A = int32(0x00000000)
  .field public static literal valuetype E B = int32(0x00000001)
}
```

Or, to rewrite that in C# again, the enum is equivalent to the following pseudo-C#:

```
struct E : System.Enum
{
    public int value__;
    public const E A = 0;
    public const E B = 1;
}
```

The question is: why is the magical field `value__` public?

I wasn't around for this design decision, so I'd have to make an educated guess.  My educated guess would be: how do you initialize an instance of the struct if the field is not public?

You make a constructor, which you then have to call, and that is giving work to the jitter, and what does the performance cost of that work buy you?  If the answer is "it buys me the runtime preventing myself from doing something foolish and dangerous that I shouldn't be doing in the first place and had to work really hard to do at all" then I submit to you that this is not a compelling cost-to-benefit ratio.

> Since the instance was in a hashtable and the mutation lead to a change of hash code, the instance is in the wrong "bucket" after the mutation, and the HashSet cannot function.

That's several miles past the "if it hurts when you do that then **stop doing that**" line.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to tell if there would be a performance cost of having a one-liner constructor to do the work, but I guess you are are right the explanation is performance related. The design is only successful, I think, because of this magic in the C# compiler that makes it not "see" the public field. If `value__` showed up in intellisense and could be written to (without having "to work really hard" by using `dynamic`), a lot of people would write to that field, and that would change the "practical" semantics of enums.

Comment: And it is a little strange that the compile-time binding with non-dynamic types disregards the `value__` field, while the run-time binding with `dynamic` picks and uses this field without throwing.

Comment: That last bit strikes me as a bug.

Comment: Interesting. Many of my questions here on SO try to exhibit a bug. If only the name of the magical instance field had been something with `<` and `>` characters in it, we wouldn't have been able to access it with just `boxDyn.nameOfField`.

Comment: And even if they made it private, you could still do it with reflection, right?

Comment: @Gabe Sure, see new comments to the _question_ above.

Comment: Your explanation seems to make sense, but I don't think it's correct. `var d = DayOfWeek.Monday` compiles to `ldc.i4.1; stloc.0`, and `(int)d` compiles to just `ldloc.0`. So the field isn't accessed at all: the compiler generates the same code as if the enum were the same as `int`.